# Ruby script executed by os.system() using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am facing issue while writing output of ruby script executed by os.system()

```
import os
def main():
    os.system('\\build.rb -p test > out1.txt')
    os.system('\\newRelease.rb -l bat > out2.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try to execute the code without passing the '> out1.txt' it gets executed and shows output on cmd but when I pass the parameter ' > out1.txt' it is not writing output in out1.txt. I want the output of the ruby script to be redirected to the txt file.

Comment: What are you trying to pass as parameters and where (python or ruby)?

Comment: We'll need more details to understand what the problem is. However, why do you need to invoke Ruby like this? why not write the script in Ruby itself? Also, Pythons `os.system` is not the [preferred way to run subprocesses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).

Comment: twil, Noufal Ibrahim: im trying to run a python code which contains a ruby script and the output should be redirected to a txt to maintain the result of the output

Comment: And the Ruby script cannot be replaced by Python code either?

Comment: twil, Noufal Ibrahim: im trying to execute ruby script in python script and need out put of that script in file

Comment: yes the code will be executed in python only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
from subprocess import check_output

build = check_output(['\\build.rb', '-p', 'test'])
with open('out1.txt', 'w') as out1:
    out1.write(build)

release = check_output(['\\newRelease.rb', '-l', 'bat'])
with open('out2.txt', 'w') as out2:
    out2.write(release)
```

Comment: :I have tried the above solution and getting the following error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 61, in <module>
main()
File "test.py", line 55, in main
fl=func_call()
File "test.py", line 42, in func_call
test = check_output(['..\\newRelease.rb', '-l', 'bat'])File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 568,in check_output process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__errread, errwrite) File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child startupinfo)

Comment: the error continues..WindowsError:[Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: It looks like Windows didn't know that your Ruby scripts were Ruby scripts, or perhaps the `\\` on the front does not belong there.  I'd try three things: removing the `\\`, adding `'ruby'` as an argument before each Ruby script name in the lists (possibly `ruby` with the full path if it's not in your `%PATH%`), and finally, try adding `shell=True` as an argument to `check_output` to make it more like your old `system()` calls.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.The solution which you provided helped me out.I made the following changes and the code worked out well.  build = check_output([ruby '\\build.rb', '-p', 'test'])  Thank you once again.
with open('out1.txt', 'w') as out1:
    out1.write(build)

release = check_output(['ruby','\\newRelease.rb', '-l', 'bat'])
with open('out2.txt', 'w') as out2:
    out2.write(release)